# How to add labels parallel to lines, polylines or multilines using Leaflet?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, leaflet

I want to add road name parallel to its line or if the line is curved, then the label should also be curved as in the image. How to add these name labels using Leaflet?

[image: example image]

Comment: how to add name parallel to polyline in leaflets???

Answer (score 0):

This isn't covered by the functionality of most webmap toolkits. Instead this is realized by the renderers who create the basemap that is embedded with Leaflet.

Thus, you need to setup Mapnik, Maperitive, Mapbox, ... create a mapstyle that you want and deliver it to your endusers. Otherwise you might want to adapt existing style e.g. delivered by Cloudmade, Mapquest, ... or checkout some of the very few [vector based webmap toolkits](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks).